# select matching object twice in a linq where-in clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I know that we can use the `Contains` method in generating a `where` clause in a linq query like this:

```
List<long> objectIDs = new List<long>() { 1, 1, 2 };
var objects = dbcontext.Where(o => objectIDs.Contains(o.ID))
                     .Select(o => o).ToList();
```

My question is, how will I be able to select the matching object twice if the `ID` occurs twice in the `where` condition?

Comment: You could join dbcontext with objectIDs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to select a separate copy of the object for each match.

`Select()` can only return exactly one object; you need `SelectMany()`:

```
list.SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Repeat(p, objectIDs.Count(id => id == p.ID)))
```

You could also do this faster using a join.